# Excel to DataTable finding Header columns in C#?

Tags: c#

I have few excel files, which I am iterating one by one and loading it into a DataTable.

In the excel connection string, I have set HDR = Yes.

The problem is that each Excel is having different set of data.

Some Excel have Header as first row itself, while for some,  it is coming in 2nd row.
I have tried the below code, but not getting the right output, when excel to excel differs

```
  excelConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
                                  + @"Data Source=" + filePath + ";"
                                  + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;IMEX=1;HDR=YES;TypeGuessRows=0;MAXSCANROWS=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text'";

   // Dataset filled from Excel data - Post that below code

    foreach (DataColumn column in excelDataSet.Tables[0].Columns)
                    {
                        string cName = excelDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0][column.ColumnName].ToString();
                        if (!excelDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Contains(cName) && cName != "")
                        {                        
                            column.ColumnName = cName;
                        }
                    }
```

How to set the row headers dynamically in the DataTable using C#?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in if statement, try this:

```
if ((!excelDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Contains(cName)) && (cName != ""))
```

Your code to change the column name should be ok: column.ColumnName = cName;